# How to limit log file size to a certain limit and generate another log file on reaching this limit?

Tags: batch-file

I need to list every file in a folder periodically in a log or text file. But on log file reaching a file size like 200 MB, another log file should be created instead of further increase current log file.

Currently I have the following code (mireg.bat), but it only lists the files:

```
forfiles /P D:files\ /M *.pdf /C "cmd /c echo @file && @echo @file %date% %time% >> D:\files\listpdf.log"
```

Comment: Why are you using FORFILES.  You are not even using any of the features that it provides.  You can just use the `FOR` command.  What will the new log file name be?

Comment: The new files name could be called "list_date_hour.txt" or "list_date_hour.log" and for the old files will renames them with ".old". Thanks for you supoort

Answer (score 3):

A useful strategy for log files management is moving the current log file in same directory to *_old.log overwriting existing *_old.log if the file size of the log file exceeds a specific limit.

Example batch code with comments:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem Check the file size of log file and move it if its more than 200 MiB.
call :CheckLogSize "D:\files\listpdf.log" 209715200

rem Other commands which append lines to log file.

endlocal
goto :EOF

rem The subroutine CheckLogSize must be called with two parameters: the log
rem file name without or with path as first parameter and the maximum file
rem size as second parameter.

rem Note: Windows command processor supports only 32 bit signed integers
rem which limits file size comparison to 2 GiB, i.e. 2147483647 bytes.
rem Therefore the second parameter should not be too large. It must be
rem made sure that the current file size of the log file is not exceeding
rem 2 GiB value on calling this subroutine. So better call this subroutine
rem once too often than once too rare.

:CheckLogSize
if not exist "%~1" goto :EOF
if %~z1 GTR %~2 move /Y "%~1" "%~dpn1_old%~x1" >nul
goto :EOF
```

Let us assume it takes about 4 weeks that the log file `D:\files\listpdf.log` exceeds 200 [MiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MiB).

Then it is moved to `D:\files\listpdf_old.log` which is done very fast as Windows just updates the file allocation table. No data is copied/moved on storage media.

On next log write the log file `D:\files\listpdf.log` is created again and grows in the next weeks again up to 200 MiB.

Now the condition in subroutine is again true and `D:\files\listpdf.log` is moved again to `D:\files\listpdf_old.log` overwriting the already existing `D:\files\listpdf_old.log` if it was not deleted manually in the meantime.

On next log write the log file `D:\files\listpdf.log` is created once again and so on.

The big advantage of this strategy: the currently used log file as well as the `old` version can be deleted manually at any time. And there are on storage media never more than two log files with a maximum storage usage of about 400 MiB independent on how much data is written into the log file per hour, day, week, month.

The limiting factor for log files on a storage media is the currently available free storage size and not how old a log file is or how old its entries are. So it is in my point of view best to focus mainly on file size and not on age of log entries.

I have so often missed information in a log file for example from more than 6 months ago not found in log file which limited the age of the entries to 3 months although the log file for last 3 months had only a file size of 30 KiB. It would have been of course no problem to keep the log entries of last 3 years on hard disk without any problem as for this log file there are added only rarely entries and each entry needs only a few bytes. But log file management works with age of log entries instead of log file size resulting in deleting old but useful log entries just to keep the size limited to a few KiB.

---

**Update:**

The subroutine `CheckLogSize` can be extended to move the current log file with new file name containing current date/time in format `_YYYY-MM-DD_HH-mm` appended to log file name left to file extension.

```
:CheckLogSize
if not exist "%~1" goto :EOF
if %~z1 LEQ %~2 goto :EOF
for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "FileNameDate=%%I"
set "FileNameDate=%FileNameDate:~0,4%-%FileNameDate:~4,2%-%FileNameDate:~6,2%_%FileNameDate:~8,2%-%FileNameDate:~10,2%"
move /Y "%~1" "%~dpn1_%FileNameDate%%~x1" >nul
set "MaxFiles=%~3"
if not defined MaxFiles set "MaxFiles=5"
for /F "skip=%MaxFiles% eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~dpn1_????-??-??_??-??%~x1" /A-D-R-H /B /O-N 2^>nul') do del "%~dp1%%I"
goto :EOF
```

The subroutine deletes also older log files no longer needed. The newest `MaxFiles` log files as defined by third parameter are kept and just the other, older log files according to date/time in file name are deleted by the subroutine. The default value is `5` for `MaxFiles` if the subroutine `CheckLogSize` is called without third parameter with number of newest log files to keep. Well, the `for` loop at end deletes usually just one log file on being periodically called.

A user has the freedom to delete at any time all or just some dated log files. A user can also set read-only or hidden attribute on a dated log file to prevent it from deletion by this subroutine. A log file with  date/time in file name can be also renamed by the user to prevent its deletion.

Comment: This has been very helpfull to my, but the idea is hold the old log files for several days and in this case all the old files must be renamed something like "Listpdf_hour_minute_date_old.log". Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

the logfile automatically rename itself by appending a  timestamp to the filename; for example, when the file  exceed 200.0 m want in size, it is renamed.

Robocopy gives the position after the comma rounded down, that means 200.00 M can also be 200 Mib + 10.23 Kib.

robocopy brings the time stamp and the calculation of the size of the log file.

```
@echo off
setlocal
prompt $g$s

set "Process=dir /s d:\" 

 rem set size= 150.0 m
 rem usage -> see SUB :Fsize

set      split= 50.0 m
set  "file.log=listPDF.log"
pushd "D:\files"

if errorlevel 1 exit /b %errorlevel%
call :Fsize "%split%" size.split

for /f "eol=D tokens=1-6 delims=/: " %%T in ('
robocopy /L /njh "\|" .^|find "123"')do set "TS=%%T%%U%%V-%%W%%X%%Y"
set "empty.tmp=%temp%\%TS% .."
md "\\?\%empty.tmp%"
for %%F in ("%file.log%")Do (
  set     "file.tmp=%%~nF-tmp%%~xF"
  set "file.TS.log=%%~nF_%TS%%%~xF"
)

> "%file.tmp%" echo LOGTIME ----- %TS% -----
>>"%file.tmp%" 2>&1 (
 %process%
)

for /f "skip=2tokens=6*" %%a in ('
   robocopy /L /njh "%empty.tmp%\\" . /IF "%file.log%" "%file.tmp%" /nfl /ndl ^|find " 0 "
') do call :Fsize "%%b" size.out deci.mal pre

if NOT %size.out% gtr %size.split% (
  echo rem "%file.log%"  %deci.mal% %pre% ^< = %split% 
  >>"%file.log%" type nul
  copy /b "%file.log%" /b +"%file.tmp%" "%file.log%"
  del "%file.tmp%"
)else (
  echo rem "%file.log%"  %deci.mal% %pre% ^> %split%
  ren "%file.log%" "%file.TS.log%"
  ren "%file.tmp%" "%file.log%"
)
popD
rd "\\?\%empty.tmp%"
exit/b

 rem END script

:Fsize "512.0 k" [VAR1-floating point [VAR2-to display only [VAR3-prefix]]]
 rem to use with output of robocopy 
 rem set with decimal minimum 1/1     max b  =1024
 rem set with decimal minimum 1/10    max k  =.9    rounded + 102.3  bytes (+  10 %)
 rem          decimal minimum 1/100   max m  =.99   rounded + 10.23  KiB   (+   1 %)
 rem          decimal minimum 1/1000  max g  =.999  rounded + 1.023  MiB   (+ 0,1 %)
 rem 500.0 b        -> 500      bytes
 rem 200.5 k        -> 200,5    KiB
 rem 350.04 m       -> 350,04   MiB
 rem 1.001 g        -> 1,001    GiB
 rem VAR1 size.out  - Binary prefix and number to floating point
 rem VAR2 deci.mal  - Reverse the calculation part to display only
 rem VAR3 pre.fix   - Reverse the calculation to add prefix
set/a p=-1,TC=10000
for %%N in (b k m g t p)Do set /a "p+=1,%%N=p"
for /f "tokens=1-3delims=. " %%A in ("%~1 0 b")Do (
  set/a"pre.fix=TC*(%%C+1) + %%A"
  set "deci.mal=%%A.%%B"
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  set "FS=!pre.fix!.%%B"
  for /f "tokens=1,2" %%S in  ("!FS! !deci.mal!")Do (
    endlocal
    if NOT "%~2"=="" (set "%~2=%%S")else set "size.out=%%S"
    if NOT "%~3"=="" set "%~3=%%T"
  )
)
set/ax=pre.fix/TC-1
for %%s in (b k m g t p)Do 2>nul set/a"N/=(%%s-x)"||if NOT "%~4"=="" (set "%~4=%%s")else set "pre.fix=%%s" 

exit /b
```

The code was reworked.

[logfile](/questions/tagged/logfile) [robocopy](/questions/tagged/robocopy) [timestamp](/questions/tagged/timestamp) [batch-rename](/questions/tagged/batch-rename)

Comment: Hello, this is a good idea and working but it not read correctly the size of the log file. :/

Comment: can you give an Output example from this command, please:     `robocopy /L /njh D:\files ".. ListOnly ..\\"  /IF "listPDF.log" /nfl /ndl ` like this one `    Verzeich.:         1         1         0         0         0         0
      Dateien:       211       211         0         0         0         0
        Bytes:  147.95 m  147.95 m         0         0         0         0
`

Comment: I already run with this script and almost always generate a new log file "listPDF.log" and renamed the old file with "listPDF_date-hhmmss.log" but the idea is that only generate a new log file if this los file has a size of 100  MB or something like that. :/

Comment: Please excuse my bad documentation. The line with the `set split= 30.0 k` variable is used to set the size from which a new file is to be created. `Set split= 30.0 k` means 30 kilobytes (ie 30 x 2 ^ 10 bytes). If the new LOG is to be created with a value of 100 MB: This line (13) is to be changed to `set split= 100.0 m` for your purposes.

Comment: With perform this change with a log file that has 13.00 KB and still creating the a new file  "listPDF_date-hhmmss.log" and also keep the original file "ListPDF.log"

Comment: @ObedSilva SilvaThe code was reworked.
More meaningful design of variables.
Removing the log size by another position in the output of a modified robocopy input.

The log should now be provided with the correct size with time stamp.

Comment: now working fine, thanks a lot, This will serve me as a basis for debugging what I wanted.